# Installing MIT Scheme on Windows 10 -- 'Requested Allocation is too large'

Tags: installation, scheme, sicp, mit-scheme

I'm trying to get Scheme going so I can work through "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" but I keep running into the above-mentioned issue. I know sort of how to solve the problem but I don't know how to go about setting the file in the `bin` directory to `--library` and `--edit` for the other directory. Can someone give me an idea if I'm supposed to use git bash, cmd, File directories(properties option)? I looked at properties and I did not find how to edit the file in such a manner.

The version of Scheme I'm using is MIT-GNU Scheme.

Comment: use Racket. ___

Comment: I'm using MIT-GNU Scheme. Is Racket basically Scheme but with extra features?

Comment: Racket is this whole big thing in itself. it has different languages, and I even saw it  mentioned here and there that it has a special SICP  language too. Lots of modern-looking help, written in a style which can be hard to follow sometimes though. Its own dedicated IDE with debugger. And yes, lots of additional features. there's a Q&A on SO about Scheme and Racket comparison, look it up. Also the "racket" tag is much more active on SO than "mit-scheme" so it can be easier to get answers. :)

Comment: Thanks I downloaded it and it seems pretty cool

Comment: Hey @Rainer, I am experiencing the same problem and wondering whether I should switch to Racket. Did Racket suffice for the course "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs"?

Comment: Yes, but you have to download sicp library in Racket. There are videos on how to do it but I can't post them at the moment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the SICP package in Racket.

1. Download Racket for your OS - https://download.racket-lang.org/
2. Follow instructions here to install the sicp package : https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html

I just did it and got it running in minutes.

Answer (score 3):

> The releases provide binaries that run on i386 and x86-64 machines under the following operating systems: GNU/Linux and OS X. We additionally provide binaries for selected other architectures and systems, depending on the hardware and software that is available to us. We no longer support OS/2, DOS, or Windows.

from [MIT/GNU Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/)